# Adding a custom header in every page of LaTeX documentclass article

Tags: header-footer

Is it possible to add a header in LaTeX documentclass `article` like in 
below format in every page?

[image: ****]

Comment: Welcome, packages like `scrlayer-scrpage`, `titleps` and `fancyhdr` can do that for you. So, yes, it is possible.

Comment: An example using `scrlayer-scrpage`: `\documentclass[headsepline]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setlength{\headheight}{51.60028pt}
\ihead{\includegraphics[width=4\baselineskip]{example-image-1x1}\begin{tabular}[b]{l}{\huge
 A very long Institute name} \\
 Address of the institution
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
Usual text, no ducks in here.
\end{document}` Code in comments is displayed bad, because the comment section is not for code blocks.

Comment: @Johannes_B Then, why not show the code in a answer? In fact, the contents of your comments  are really an answer.

Comment: @Fran Because i don't like to answer the most simple questions that can be answered by a two minute google search.

Comment: @Fran The answer that fits the question would be: *Yes, it is possible*. Which is not very helpful.

Comment: @Johannes_B I understand you position, but this way could remain "unanswered" forever. Moreover, such answers  with a MWE are very useful for novices, even if this is explained in almost any LaTeX tutorial.

Comment: @Fran There is an answer below. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `fancyhdr` approach. Depending on the height/size of the logo and the text, the `\headwidth` length has to be adapted (here `55pt` in my case, have a look into the `.log` file for recommendations from `fancyhdr` output)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[headheight=55pt]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead[L]{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{beeduck}%
      \end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[b]{l}
        Ministry Of Silly Walks  \tabularnewline
        Head of Department: The Bee Duck\tabularnewline
        Vice chairmen: The Duck Bee\tabularnewline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}   
  }%
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]